# HMAC-SHA512 в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть необходимость создать хеш по алгоритму HMAC-SHA512 в Delphi.
В Indy нашел модуль IdHMACSHA1. В нем есть классы (TIdHMACSHA1, TIdHMACSHA224, TIdHMACSHA256, TIdHMACSHA384, TIdHMACSHA512), реализующие соответствующие алгоритмы создания хеша. Но вот беда робит только TIdHMACSHA1. Остальные выдают пустую строку хеша. Может я конечно что-то не так делаю. Насколько я понял нужно задать Key и вызвать HashValue. Ну например так:

```
var MyKey,MyData:string;
................................
...Инициализация MyKey,MyData...
with TIdHMACSHA512.Create do
  try
     Key := ToBytes(MyKey);
     Showmessage(StringOf(HashValue(ToBytes(MyData))));
   finally
     Free;
   end;
................................
```

Выдает пустую строку. По тому же принципу TIdHMACSHA1 выдает нормальный хеш.
Может есть другие библиотеки с реализованной функцией HMAC-SHA512?
Или все-таки придется изучать доку по HMAC-SHA512 и пилить алгоритм самому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В саом инди есть реализация только SHA-1. Все остальные хеши он берет из openssl. Поэтому вам надо подгрузить библиотеку перед расчетом.

> IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary